# Preview button causes an error in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

It use to work great under rails 2 and now moving to rails 3 as caused my code to have errors.

Error Message:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Slice of code:

```
<div id="archive-list">
  <h4>Archives</h4>
  <ul>
  <% @archive_list.each do |item| -%>
<li><%= link_to(item[0], archive_url(:year => item[1], :month => item[2])) %></li>
  <% end -%>
  </ul>
```

there seems to be an issue with:

<% @archive_list.each do |item| -%>

with this line above

Any help would be great?

Comment: Can you post your controller code for this view?

Answer (score 0):

`@archive_list` is probably `nil`

do a `puts @archive_list` in the controller before rendering the view and check if it's nil

in the view you could do a `<% if @archive_list.exists? %>` before iterating over it, if it's an active record relation, or `<% if @archive_list.blank? %>` if it's something else (from the looks of the code it's the latter).